# How to pass null property to register_object

Tags: rust, gio

When calling `registry_object`, the following does not work:

```rust
use gio::DBusConnection;

let dbus_connection: DBusConnection = ...
dbus_connection.register_object(
  path,
  self.introspection_data.unwrap(),
  self.handle_method_call,
  None, //get_property
  None, //set_property
).unwrap();
```

Both arguments `get_property` and `set_property` want a fn but I have no idea how to map this function so that I would be null - similar to C. Setting `None` does not work :(

Comment: What is `DBusConnection`? How it is defined, what's the semantics of these arguments?

Comment: Perhaps the nomicons [FFI section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html) would be of interest to you. You can create null by `std::ptr::null()`.

Comment: Assuming this is the [`DBusConnection` from gtk-rs](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/gio/struct.DBusConnection.html#method.register_object), then I don't think you can. The corresponding [source code](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/src/gio/dbus_connection.rs.html#79-166) appears to require valid functions (or closures) there.